# Plotting Multiple Data from Serial Port Using Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, serial-port

I am using PSoC microcontroller (CY8CKIT-043) to sense pressure. So far, I can successfully display the pressure data using Tera Term. I have three data to display namely Normal, maximum, and minimum. These are all real-time data changing with time. Now I want to create a Windows App and plot these data on a Chart in real-time. I am a new user of Windows Form. Please, can someone, help me with the coding or a way to start.

I already tried displaying the data using Tera Term and I can successfully display the data from the port

None

To display the plot of the 3 pressure values in Windows Form.

Comment: See msdn for sample chart programs : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/samples-environments-for-b01e9c61/view/samplepack

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use SerialPlot serial data plotting tool to plot the measured pressure. SerialPlot is an open source realtime plotting software. You can download SerialPlot from https://bitbucket.org/hyOzd/serialplot/downloads/
2. Bridge Control Panel available as part of PSoC Creator supports chart feature. You can refer to this video for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93X2z6PE71I